# Logging google users via my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

Is there a way to authenticate google users via chrome extension? Currently, seems like manifest V2 is deprecated and manifest V3 does not support it.

Tried using manifest V3 and it keeps asking me for redirect uri (I don't have a domain).